# Concatenate Cell Values Dynamically And Copy Result to Another Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet ("Data") with x-columns and y-rows. I want to concatenate the values of a row and the concatenated result should be copied to a second worksheet ("Insert") in the first column of the same row.

I tried this VBA and get an error message

```
Sub InsertStatementRow()
Dim x As String, rng As Range, rng1 As Range, cel As Range
Dim ColMax As Integer
Dim i As Long

    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select

        ColMax = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        With Worksheets("Data")
        i = 1
        Set rng = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, ColMax))
        End With

        For Each cel In rng

            x = x & cel.Value

        Next

        Range(Sheets("Insert").Cells(i, 1)).Value = x

End Sub
```

Please show me what I am doing wrong by correcting my code. Thanks!

Comment: if you record a macro, you'll get the general syntax of what you need to do.  Take a look at that, and see if you can modify to suit your situation.  If you're still stuck, post what you tried and what doesn't work about it.

Comment: It seems something got mixed up in posting this thread. The question I need to be answered is about the CONCATENATE VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some **"."** :

```
Set rng = Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, ColMax))
```

Comment: When I run my script (with your proposal implemented) I receive an error for the code line "Range(Sheets("Insert").Cells(i, 1)).Value = x"

Comment: then use:  **Sheets("Insert").Cells(i,1).Value=x**